Jest encountered an unexpected token. By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers
Im Running a Test File and Getting the Following Error
● Test suite failed to run

    Jest encountered an unexpected token

    Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

I Tried Adding Babel But It didn't work.
I thought I might just need to add jest.config.json but I don't know how to implement it.
Sorry I'm pretty new with this things.
This is My ts.config.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

This is My Test File.
import React from "react"
import { Provider } from "react-redux"

import configureStore from "redux-mock-store"
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

// import { expect, describe, it } from "@jest/globals"
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react"

import { getAlgoList } from "store/slice/AlgorithmList/AlgorithmListActions"

// eslint-disable-next-line no-relative-import-paths/no-relative-import-paths
import { AlgorithmTreeView } from "./TreeView"

jest.mock("store/slice/AlgorithmList/AlgorithmListActions", () => ({
  getAlgoList: jest.fn(),
}))

const mockStore = configureStore([thunk])

describe("AlgorithmTreeView", () => {
  let store: ReturnType<typeof mockStore>

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore({...})
})

  it("renders the AlgorithmTreeView component", () => {
    render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AlgorithmTreeView />
      </Provider>,
    )

    expect(screen.getByText("Data")).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText("Algorithm")).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText("node1")).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(screen.getByText("node2")).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

etc...

I Tried Adding Babel But It Didn't work.

How did you try adding babel?
